# How to type check a nested list of integers and convert to string?

Tags: python, operators, typing, control-flow, generic-collections

If I have kwargs that have list and integer values,  how do I type check the items in a for if loop?
I keep getting `TypeError: 'int' is not iterable` or it skips the if statement.

I've tried operators `==`, `!=`, `is`, `is not` with `list`, `List`, `iter`, `type(list)` and `int`

Example:
If my kwargs are...

```
kwargs = {'foo': [1, 2], 'bar': 2, 'baz': 3}
new_list = []
for kw, args in kwargs.items():
    if args == list:
        for arg in args:
            new_list.append(str(arg))
    else:
        new_list.append(str(args))
print(new_list)
>>> ['[1, 2]', '2', '3']
```

and if I switch the if statement to `if args != int:` I get `TypeError: 'int' is not iterable`

Comment: If you want to check if something is a list, you could do `if isinstance(args, list):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a variable is a list you can simply write:

```py
if isinstance(var, list):
    pass
```

But if a variable could be anything iterable, use typing module.

```py
from typing import Iterable  # or from collections.abc import Iterable

if isinstance(var, Iterable):
    pass
```

There are many other abstract base classes you can use, so I would suggest reading the documentation to learn about them.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html